# for-in-loop/ Condition Is only used for the first element of the a List

Tags: c#, list, indexing, conditional-statements, for-in-loop

I have searched for three days and didn't find a solution, Here is the code:

```
if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
{
    for (int i = GlobalClass.BlocksPositions.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (new Rectangle((int)GlobalClass.BlocksPositions[i].X, (int)GlobalClass.BlocksPositions[i].Y, bT.Width, bT.Height).Intersects(new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Texture.Width, Texture.Height)))
        {

            c = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            c = 1;
        }
    }

    if (c == 1)
    {
        Position.X += Speed;
    }

}
```

Each Block position equals a block that I can create by clicking on the screen, the new block position is then put in the List. Basically I have a list of blocks Coordinates in my BlockPosition List. Then I pass the condition for each blockposition, the Condition Create A rectangle for each BlockPosition and one for the Player... if there's a collision, the player won't move in that direction. When I try the code, My character will Collide only with the first element of the List and not the others, if I delete the first element it will then collide with the next one but not the others. All the variables are FINE I know it because I tried to replace this code by something like this:

```
if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
{
    for (int i = GlobalClass.BlocksPositions.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (new Rectangle((int)GlobalClass.BlocksPositions[i].X, (int)GlobalClass.BlocksPositions[i].Y, bT.Width, bT.Height).Intersects(new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Texture.Width, Texture.Height)))
        {
            GlobalClass.BlocksPositions.RemoveAt[i];

        }
    }
}
```

Same thing but here if it collides I delete the Element of the List, it's the same condition but when I try it it will detect all of the elements and delete the ones that I touch. I tried the foreach function and I get the same Results. What's wrong? I already do a lot of things with does variables So I'm sure the problem don't come from their values but with what I do with them. Help please! (:

Comment: NEVER MIND I found how!! I just had to put a break in it after the c = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readability, consider something like this:

```
if (GlobalClass.BlocksPositions.All(x => !DoesIntersect(Position, x))
     Position.X += speed;
```

Not only is the purpose easier to deduce, but the particular mistake you made just doesn't come up.

Comment: That changes the semantics of the code.  the X position will be updated once at most in your example, but in the OP's it will be increased for every rectangle which does not intersect until an intersection is found.

Comment: Untrue.  Position.X is modified outside of the for-loop and is specifically nested within two if-blocks, so it can only logically be executed once in this code fragment.  In his case, such an increment will only occur if the final block in the collection and the position do not intersect.  There is no break condition specified when an intersection is found.

Answer (score 2):

You don't do anything if the `if` evaluates to `true`, and you don't seem to need the `c` variable anyway.  How about...

```
if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
{
    foreach( var pos in GlobalClass.BlocksPositions.Reverse() )
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle((int)pos.X, (int)pos.Y, bT.Width, bT.Height);
        var rectToTest = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Texture.Width, Texture.Height);
        if (!rect.IntersectsWith(rectToTest))
            Position.X += Speed;
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

If you actually do need `c` for some sort of state management then you can add it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop continues even when you've found an intersection.  You need a break in the true clause of the if-statement.